woocommerce email without prices
I am trying to make the new_order_admin mail not show the prices of the product, it should only show the name and quantity ordered.
I can't find the code to do it.
Does anyone know how to do it?
I tried with pulgins and touching the php but I can't identify the corresponding hook or I can't find the right code.

Show your work, in text form, please.
